# Building a key logger with Pynput (saving it to notepad)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger, pynput

Trying to build a key logger with pynput.

Took a look at [Here](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard), everything worked fine but not what I wanted, I wanted to save the output to a text file at the same time that the programs running.

I tried `sys.stdout` but it just dosent save it to the LogTXT.txt file.

Anyways, here's the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

import os

import atexit

import sys

file = os.open(r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\LogTXT.txt",  os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT )

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
    sys.stdout = file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use another way to do this instead of use the `stdout`,think it as another way:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

fp = open(r"LogTXT_{}.txt".format(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())),"w") # open the file

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
    fp.write('{} pressed at time:{}\n\n'.format(key,time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime()))) # write it.

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    fp.write('{} release at time:{}\n\n'.format(key,time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())))
    if key == Key.esc:
        fp.write("End Press") # press esc.Exit the script
        fp.close()
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Some example of output in the file:
[image]

Comment: still didn't save it to the text file.

Comment: @Daniel Well.look the path,it save in the current path.

Comment: I know it does create a text file but doesn't save the output to that file.